# How to inspect a neovim variable?

Tags: neovim

I am trying to inspect a lua variable whose name is `bufferline.options.indicator`

How does one inspect a lua variable in Neovim ?

Comment: In Vim, I would traditionally do `:echo <var>` or `:PP <var>` with scriptease. Maybe something like `:lua print <var>` or whatever the syntax is?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have tried `lua print(vim.opt.scrolloff)` which set to 1024 for example, but I only get a `table 0xdeadbeefdead`

I didn´t know about PP !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **The `=` syntax**

`:lua =var`

In version **0.9**, you don't even need to type in `lua` :

`:=var` will do.

- **The `vim.print()` syntax**

Before version 0.9, there was `:lua vim.pretty_print(var)`

Now with 0.9, `vim.pretty_print` has been renamed to `vim.print` so it's :

`:lua vim.print(var)`

- **Lua's `print` + `vim.inspect()` syntax**

`:lua print(vim.inspect(var))`

Answer (score 0):

The command should be `nvim_buf_get_option({buffer}, {name})`, look at the `:help` page for more info.

Comment: This is the API, I meant in when you are in the editor