# How to identify names of lua configuration variables to inspect them?

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin

I load a plugin, and the plug docs tell me that I can configure it using lua code like this, which I might put in my startup file:

```
lua require('plugin_name').setup{
                              \ foo = true,
                              \ bar = { x = y },
                              \ baz = { z = { 'a', 'b' },
}
```

Suppose I want to see what these values are while nvim is running.  I know that I can use
`:lua print(...)` to display variables, and I think I might even need `:lua print(vim.inspect(...))`.  Answers to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-to-inspect-a-neovim-variable) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942289/display-contents-of-tables-in-lua) would help me if I knew what variable I was trying do inspect.

My question is: Given what I know from the plugin documentation (as shown in the code block above), what substitute for `...`?  What are the names of the lua variables and tables that are implied by the above setup code?

Comment: Unfortunately, because `setup` is usually a function it could be anything. Your best bet is probably to open whatever file defines the setup function and glance at it.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble.  Then that's the answer.  Feel free to copy what you wrote into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, because `setup` is usually a function it could be anything. Your best bet is probably to open whatever file defines the setup function and glance at it.

There’s no standard, really, although I would expect lots of the equivalent of `g:<plugin>_<var>`.